# Emulator startup stuck x86 build on AOSP 4.3 with emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970'

Tags: android, sockets, android-emulator

Getting below error while launching the emulator. The Emulatror is stuck in infinite loop with boot animation.

```
emulator: goldfish_audio_write: AUDIO_INT_ENABLE 0
emulator: goldfish_audio_write: AUDIO_INT_ENABLE 7
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 22
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 22
```

Any Pointer?

Comment: I also came across the same error when trying to run AOSP fresh build for mako in emulator. Any Ideas anyone..?

Comment: Did you eventually figure it out, or did you give up on it? If you found a solution, please post it! I'm dealing with this right now...

Comment: maybe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697270/ubuntu-all-android-emulatorx86-and-arm-stuck-on-error-while-connecting-to-so