# ubuntu: all android emulator(x86 and arm) stuck on "Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> Connection refused"

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-emulator

i have try all android emulator, but they are all stuck on following step:

```
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD =
```

this is my cli: `path/to/emulator64-x86 -avd x86 -debug all`

this is [my full log](https://gist.github.com/roroco/5780c2e0a12e18539457)

**my question is**

How to fix this error?

**my system info:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 17 Qiana
Release:    17
Codename:   qiana
```

Answer (score 3):

I just spent hours trying to figure this out.  Hopefully you found the answer but I will post this here in case anyone comes along looking for it.  I had to use the ARM cpu.  I am still looking to see if I can find a solution for x86.

1. Start your AVD and let it hang at the black screen
2. Open a terminal
3. Type `telnet localhost 5554` (your port number may differ depending on your avd port)
4. Type `redir add tcp:5000:6000`
5. Your AVD should load into the lock screen in a few seconds

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Comment: A workaround for x86 exists. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32544210/4238076).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to localhost, you need to use `10.0.2.2` on emulator.

So, in your case it should be : `10.0.2.2:1970`

If you are using `Genymotion's` emulator use `10.0.3.2` instead `10.0.2.2`.

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to do? Its been a long time i dont use LINUX

Comment: i use "path/to/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator64-x86 -avd x86 -debug all", i expect you tell me "path/to/emulator64-x86 -avd x86 -debug all -specific-url 10.0.2.2", how to specific url

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem too. I was connected to internet. So I used my actual IP address.
Use this command `ifconfig -a` and get `inet addr` . Try it please, maybe it can help you.

Comment: But there's still the question of how to update the emulator's configuration file to use the actual IP instead of `127.0.0.1`.